# Regex: Find anything after a dollar sign and replace with empty string?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a label showing size and price like: **12' x 15' - $3,906.00**

I want to find the dollar sign and remove everything including the dollar sign with a regex. I want to use `.replace()` to do this, is it possible?

Comment: what is wrong in `\$.*$`? asking from down voters.

Comment: It *is* very simple (as was said in the already-deleted answer), but I suspect the downvotes were because of "remove everything *following* it", i.e., the `$` should remain. However, I think that's what the OP *said* but did not *mean* to.

Comment: @user3218114: Don't think anything was wrong with your answer. Sometimes down votes are unwarranted.

Comment: use `str.replace(/\$.*$/,'$')`

Comment: @user3218114: I want to remove $ as well.

Comment: ok then use `str.replace(/\$.*$/,'')`

Comment: @AvinashRaj what is full code? As OP is already talked about `replace` function.

Comment: @AvinashRaj it's a single line code and the function name is already mentioned by OP then why should I repeat it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myString.replace(/\$[\s\S]*$/, "$")
```

The `\$` matches the (in this case first) literal dollar sign in the string.

The `[\s\S]*` matches a run of any characters including newlines.

The final `$` matches the end of input.

The `"$"` is the value to replace the matched content with.  Since you only wanted to get rid of the content *after* the dollar sign, your replacement string has to have the dollar sign.

---

Alternatively, `myString.substring(0, myString.indexOf('$') + 1)` will work just as well as long as there's always a dollar sign in the string.

Comment: Why is it better to use `[\s\S]` instead of `.`?

Comment: Hmm .. it's showing the specail characters instead of doing the replacement. I'm using jQuery but am using `jQuery(".item-options dd")[0].replace(/\$[\s\S]*$/, "$")` .. is something wrong?

Comment: @uʍop ǝpısdn, because `.` does not match newlines and the question doesn't explicitly exclude them.

Comment: @uʍop ǝpısdn, `$` matches end-of-input in JavaScript, not end-of-line since there is no `m` flag on the regex.

Answer (score 0):

Better use `String#substring()` and `String#indexOf()` functions instead of using regex.

Sample code:

```
var str="12' x 15' - $3,906.00";
console.log(str.substring(0,str.indexOf('$')));
```